# How to set text to a title when it is using document listener?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, document, illegalstateexception

I have a `JTextField` and in which I need to edit or add new content into the text field. Am able to get the text after while using document listener but not able to set text. It throws error like

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    Attempt to mutate in notification
```

My code:

```
    t_pageno.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        warn();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        warn();
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        warn();
    }

    public void warn() {
        if (
                Integer.parseInt(t_pageno.getText()) > Integer.parseInt(Config.maxpageno) 
                && 
                Integer.parseInt(t_pageno.getText()) < 0
                ) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Error: Please enter number bigger than 0 and less than "+Config.maxpageno, "Error Massage",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        else
        {
        String pageno = t_pageno.getText();
            if (!pageno.equals(new File(Current_index).getName().substring(18, 20))) {
                int Storyidconfirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do You want to change the Page No", "Change PageNo", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (Storyidconfirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    String newidchange = new File(Current_index).getName().substring(0, 18) + pageno + new File(Current_index).getName().substring(21, new File(Current_index).getName().length());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Change in page no ??????????");
                }
                else
                {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reversing to old page no");
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "new File(Current_index).getName().substring(18, 20) --> "+new File(Current_index).getName().substring(18, 20));
                   t_pageno.setText(new File(Current_index).getName().substring(18, 20).toString());                             
                }
        }
        }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`DocumentListener` isn't a good place to try and make modifications to the `Document`, as when it is notified, the `Document` is in a state of mutation, so any attempt to further modify it will cause it to throw an `IllegalStateException`

If you want to change or filter the text before it is committed to the `Document` you should use a `DocumentFilter` instead, this is what it's designed for.

See [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more details.

You should only ever use a `DocumentListener` when you want to be notified of changes to the `Document` AFTER they have already been committed to the the `Document` and never try and use it to filter or otherwise modify the `Document` in anyway

I would also, strongly, discourage you from showing an alert on each update, as this would just be annoying.  Instead, I would highlight the field in some way, indicating that the value value is invalid (maybe providing a tooltip for further information) and/or update some kind of status value/label.  I might consider using an `ActionListener` and/or `InputVerifier` to perform the physical validation and then display an error to the user, so they may make a mistake as they are typing and correct before they want the change to be actioned on.

I'd also encourage you to have a look at `JSpinner`

See [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) and [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) for more details

Comment: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, .., should be delayed by invokeLater

Comment: @mKorbel In the case, I'd avoid it all together, pulling up a `JOptionPane` because the user typed a character wrong is just a pain the ass and there are better ways to let the user know they've violating what ever rules you have in place, but that's just me